# Excel Slicers connected to Shared Pivots but Disconnected from one Pivot

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 2 Pivot tables that share 2 slicers, Name and product and a third slicer which filter the **Month**. the third slicer is only connected to one Pivottable

Is there a way when I filter for a specific Month, the Name and product with no data is visually indicated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're talking about "Show items with No Data"

In the **PivotTable Fields** section, click on the **downward arrow** on Name & Product and select **Field Settings** and check the **"Show items with No Data"** option in the **Layout & Print** section

[image]